# What does it mean to say that int enum patterns are compile-time constants?

Tags: java, enums, effective-java, compile-time-constant

This is from Effective Java

> Programs that use the int enum pattern are brittle. Because int enums are
>   compile-time constants, they are compiled into the clients that use them.

Can some one explain why the int enum pattern is  called compiled type constant and what is meant by **compiled into the clients**?

Here s' an example of such a constant :

```
public static final int APPLE_FUJI = 0;
```

Comment: It is one of the few optimisation `javac` does and in general I would rather it didn't ;)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Suppose you have two files:

```
Foo.java:
public class Foo
{
    public static final int SOMETHING = 1;
}

Bar.java:
public class Bar
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println(Foo.SOMETHING);
    }
}
```

Compile them both, run `java Bar` and it will print out 1.

Now change Foo.java so that `SOMETHING` is 2, and recompile *just Foo.java*. Rerun `java Bar` and it will *still* print 1. The constant value will be copied to every piece of code that uses it, rather than asking for the value from `Foo` at execution time.

In practice, *if* you recompile everything any time anything changes, this isn't a problem.

Comment: isn't Java a dynamic binding language ? Why do we have to recompile everything ?

Comment: @Geek You don't **have** to do it. But it is highly recommended in order to avoid what Jon Skeet is describing above. This behaviour of the Java compiler is a bad one, in my opinion. That constant should only be stored in `Foo.class`. `Bar` should ALWAYS get that constant from `Foo`. Like many other semi-stupid things in a language: it won't be changed because maybe it will break existing code. What a bunch of cry-babies...

Comment: @Geek: You'd have to define "dynamic binding language" for me to answer your first question. But the reason you have to recompile in this case is because the language specification explicitly calls out constant expressions like this.

Comment: @Jon dynamic binding in the sense that the clients of Foo should ask Foo for any constant belonging to Foo at run time (ie dynamic).

Comment: Types (classes) are bound dynamically but, as mentioned, constants are not. It's an optimization. If you want to preserve dynamic typing use real enums instead of int constants.

Answer (score 6):

The value '0' itself will be built into the `.class` files during compilation. If you then change that value, you have to recompile *everything* that uses it, including any client's code that uses your application/library.

If you don't, you won't get a warning, but rather incorrect behaviour.

If your compile-time constant is used solely in your code then it's less of a problem, assuming a complete clean/build cycle. If your code then reaches a wider audience then this becomes more of a problem.