# Compiler says an annotation's "value must be a constant"

Tags: java, annotations, java-8

I have a Spring<sup>1</sup> `@Controller` annotated class with `@RequestMapping` annotated methods. I want to reference values for the `@RequestMapping` parameters, `value` and `method`, from another class, rather than hard coding them into the annotation.

#### Example

Instead of

```
@Controller
public class MyController {
    @RequestMapping(value="my/path", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String handlePath() {
        // etc...
    }
}
```

I want two files,

```
@Controller
public class MyController {
    @RequestMapping(value=Constants.PATH, method=Constants.PATH_METHOD)
    public String handlePath() {
        // etc...
    }
}
```

and

```
public class Constants {
    public static final String PATH = "my/path";
    public static final RequestMethod PATH_METHOD = RequestMethod.GET;
}
```

Unfortunately, this fails with the following compile-time error:

```
error: an enum annotation value must be an enum constant
        @RequestMapping(value=Constants.PATH, method=Constants.PATH_METHOD)
                                                              ^
```

#### Question

Why does this work in the case of `String` but does not work for `enum`s?

---

#### Notes

1. This question is not Spring specific, this is just an (hopefully) accessible example of this issue.
2. I happen to be using Java 8

Comment: In your second part you still use Constants.Path and Constants.Path_Method shouldn't it just be Path and Path_Method...

Comment: @brso05 you are right, that was a copy-paste error, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We need to look at what the Java Language Specification says is [an acceptable value for an annotation method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.7.1).

> It is a compile-time error if the element type is not commensurate
>   with the element value. An element type `T` is commensurate with an
>   element value `V` if and only if one of the following is true:
>
> - If `T` is a primitive type or `String`, then `V` is a constant expression (§15.28).
> - If `T` is an `enum` type (§8.9), then V is an `enum` constant (§8.9.1).

`PATH_METHOD` is not an [`enum` constant](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.9.1). `RequestMethod.GET` is an `enum` constant. For `String`, this

```
public static final String PATH = "my/path";
```

is a constant variable, which is a constant expression and therefore can be used.

It shouldn't work even if the constant was declared in the same file. Please review.

Comment: Ah, you're right; I knew the `String` part compiled, so I assumed the `enum` would too but it doesn't, shame on me (edited question slightly to account for this). I guess this is because "`enum` constant" has a stronger definition than "constant expression"? Half of the original question still stands: what's the difference when the String is defined inside and outside the particular class? (Maybe this is a bug in javac?) And a harder question: why are annotations designed this way?

Comment: @kuporific Edited for `String` case. Again, it's not about where the value is defined, it's about the characteristics of the value.

Comment: @kuporific I don't have an answer for the why.

Comment: @kuporific: there is no difference between inside and outside declarations; the `String` part works for me so you might recheck whether you really did the setup right. The question about why is not so hard: annotations are compile-time constants and part of the class invariants, just like a `public` modifier, for example. They may be processed by development tools without actually executing the code. And since annotations are compile-time constants they must be composed of compile-time constants only.

Comment: @Holger "there is no difference between inside and outside declarations" you're right, the code I was playing with was slightly more complicated, and had a separate issue (edited question). I see that my issue is with how Java is *defined*, but I don't see a technical reason why the the language couldn't be defined such that the enum case worked.

Comment: @kuporific: that’s a different question. I just answered to “why are annotations designed this way?” The other question is “why are `enum` constants not compile-time constants” for which the most likely answer is: “just historical reasons”. `enum`s where introduced in Java 5 but the definition of compile-time constants did not change. The possibility to refer to `enum` constants in `switch` statements or annotations was added as a separate language construct instead of redefining compile-time constants and that created this asymmetry.

Comment: @Holger It turns out "Why aren't `enum` constants compile-time constants?" is answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11773441/what-does-it-mean-to-say-that-int-enum-patterns-are-compile-time-constants If `enum`s *were* compile-time constants, consumers of an `enum` would have to be recompiled if the `enum` changed.

Comment: @kuporific: no, that question is about (ab)using `int` values as enumerations. If the Java language supported `enum` values as compile-time constants it used the symbolic name rather than `int` values, just as `switch` statements, annotations and Serialization already do. Of course, changing a class declaring compile-time constants in an incompatible way will break classes using them, but that’s not different to `String` or primitive type compile-time constants.